# Was there an OSCE mission observing the Scottish independence referendum?

Tags: election, referendum, scotland, osce

Even though the United Kingdom is an established democracy, the Organization for Security and Co-operation in Europe (OSCE) [did observe](https://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/uk/317311) for instance the 2017 general election. There's both a "needs report" (which did recommend a small mission) as well as final report (both are found on the previously linked page). The mission's scope was rather limited:

> In line with ODIHR’s methodology, the EET will not carry out systematic or comprehensive observation of voting, counting, or tabulation on election day. Team members will, however, visit a small number of polling stations across the country to follow election day procedures.

There's also the UK's government [response to the reports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/669980/Gov_Response_to_OSCE_Report_on_General_Election_.pdf).

I can't find something similar for the 2014 Scottish referendum though. Was there an OSCE mission observing it?

(The OSCE site is a bit of a mess, so it's possible I missed something or they don't have older stuff on-line.)

I did find a response from the (then) Irish Minister for Foreign Affairs and Trade, Charles Flanagan to a July 2014 Dáil question in which [he said](https://www.kildarestreet.com/wrans/?id=2014-07-16a.102)

> No invitation from the EU or the OSCE to send election observers to monitor the forthcoming Scottish Independence Referendum on 18 September has been received nor is one expected.

It's clear from that that the Irish didn't receive an invitation to monitor the Scottish referendum (via an EU or OSCE mission), but it's a little less clear whether the UK didn't invite the OSCE at all.

Comment: Why would a nation which is generally accepted as democratic need observers to their elections? Three reasons I can think of: Establishing a precedent that such observer groups do not necessarily mean distrust or disrespect of the host country, keeping everyone honest, and a chance to learn from best international best practice. But that doesn't mean *every* poll needs to be monitored.

Comment: @o.m.: Given that the Scottish referendum turned out to be the poll with the highest percentage of people thinking it was affected by fraud... after the fact (according to the  Electoral Commission) and given that before the poll 19% thought it was going to be rigged... (Let me know if you needs link to those facts.)

Comment: even if people are complaining, and even if there were *individual* cases of misconduct, elections in the UK are not remotely close to, say, Congo.

Comment: @o.m.: Sure, but what I'm saying is that if OSCE observers were ever warranted in the UK, the Scottish ref would have been it. The UK did admit Russian observers for whatever reason, see link below James' answer for that.

Comment: Does the OSCE monitor votings if they are not *invited*? Perhaps the Russians invited themselves (your link in your comment to James K's answer suggest that they were there with a pro-Kremlin agenda) and they were just *allowed*, which is an important distinction.

Comment: @SJuan76: yes there seems to be that distinction. But if you allow any Tom Dick and Harry to "monitor" your election, why not invite some reputable org as well? Ok, maybe the why should be a different question. In this one I thought I had actually missed something that had happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The OSCE lists the [elections that it has observed in the UK](https://www.osce.org/odihr/elections/uk)

It sent small teams to 2005, 2010, 2015 and 2017 elections, and to the 2003 elections to the devolved administrations in Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland. It seems likely that had it been invited to observe the independence, AV or "brexit" referendums, it would have done so. Therefore it is a reasonable assumption that the UK does not normally invite the OSCE to observe referendums.

Comment: It seems rather odd given that it allowed numerous other observers https://www.occrp.org/en/investigations/5368-brexit-how-russian-influence-undermines-public-trust-in-referendums at least on the Scottish referendum.